# How to allow rw NFS share in a heterogeneous environment (GNU/Linux, Windows)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, nfs, nfs4, network-filesystem

I have a NFS server on Ubuntu 20.04. My /etc/exports looks like

```
/home/user2 10.4.200.2(rw,sync)
/home/user3 10.4.200.3(rw,sync)
```

On a Windows 10, I mount the folder using "Connect a network storage" (Sorry, it might not be an accurate translation because the system language is not English). I enter in the folder field

```
IP_of_the_server:/home/user2
```

However, the remote NFS storage appears in read-only mode. Indeed, I cannot create nor delete files.

Answer (score 0):

I added two keys in Windows registry in order to make the mapping.

1. Open regedit by typing it in the search box end pressing Enter.
2. Browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ClientForNFS\CurrentVersion\Default.
3. Create a new New DWORD (32-bit) Value inside the Default folder named AnonymousUid and assign the UID found on the UNIX directory as shared by the NFS system.
4. Create a new New DWORD (32-bit) Value inside the Default folder named AnonymousGid and assign the GID found on the UNIX directory as shared by the NFS system. Windows 10: Regedit NFS AnonymousUid and AnonymousGid
5. Restart the NFS client or reboot the machine to apply the changes.

Source
https://graspingtech.com/mount-nfs-share-windows-10/